# terraform: command not found in gitlab CI environment

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have following CI configurations:

```
variables:
  TF_ROOT: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
  TF_ADDRESS: ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.terraformrc

default:
  image: hashicorp/terraform:light

cache:
  key: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  paths:
    - ${TF_ROOT}/.terraform


before_script:
  - echo -e "credentials \"$CI_SERVER_HOST\" {\n  token = \"$CI_JOB_TOKEN\"\n}" > $TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE
  - cd ${TF_ROOT}
  - export TF_LOG_CORE=TRACE
  - export TF_LOG_PATH=terraform_logs.txt

stages:
  - prepare

init:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - terraform -v
    - terraform init
```

But at `prepare` stage i get:

```
$ terraform -v
bash: line 135: terraform: command not found
```

My understanding is by using `hashicorp/terraform:light` as base image, i get `terraform` available throughout the runner environment but that doesn't seems to be the case.

Can anyone correct me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Added second part to my answer to reflect your changes, please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the gitlab-runner was configured to be a `shell` executor. Which makes the whole `image: hashicorp/terraform:light` part redundant and `terraform` should be installed on the host machine itself where runner is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use 'latest' image instead of 'light'. Update 'default' section with below Content. It is having entrypoint details with PATH initialized.

```
default:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:latest
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/env
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Reference : https://matavelli.io/posts/2020/01/setup-gitlab-ci-with-terraform/

Comment: No I am using `hashicorp/terraform:light` and even tried to use your part of code but i still get the same.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is by using hashicorp/terraform:light as base image,
> i get terraform available throughout the runner environment but that
> doesn't seems to be the case

But in the code you are using `gitlab-terraform` and it seems that is not available in `hashicorp/terraform:light` image.

Try the following image, from the gitlab registry

```
default:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest
```

---

If you want to use `terraform` command instead add the following

```
default:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:light
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/env
      - "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```